# Can we re-write Newton's Binomial formula as a power series in $\ r\ $ without any problems?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, binomial-theorem

Newton's [Generalised Binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem#Newton%27s_generalized_binomial_theorem) states that if $\ x\ $ and $\ y\ $ are real numbers with $\ \vert x \vert > \vert y \vert\ (\text{note that } \left\vert \frac{y}{x} \right\vert < 1),\ $ and $\ r\ $ is any complex number, one has

$$ (x+y)^r = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{r}{k} x^{r-k} y^k = x^r + \frac{r}{1!} x^{r-1} y^1 + \frac{r(r-1)}{2!} x^{r-2} y^2 + \frac{r(r-1)(r-2)}{3!} x^{r-3} y^3 + \ldots\ .$$

If we restrict $\ r\ $ to be a real number, and view this as a [power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_series) in $\ r\ $ whilst preserving the order of terms, then:

- The constant term is $\ x^r.$
- The linear coefficient, i.e. the coefficient of $\ r,\ $ whilst preserving the order of terms in Newton's formula, is

$$\frac{1}{1} x^{r-1} y^1 - \frac{1}{2} x^{r-2} y^2 + \frac{1}{3} x^{r-3} y^3 - \frac{1}{4} x^{r-2} y^2 + \ldots = x^r\left( \frac{1}{1!}\frac{y}{x} - \frac{1}{2!}\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{3!}\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^3 - \frac{6}{4!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^4 + \ldots \right)$$

I noticed that this is equal to $\ x^r \ln \left( 1 + \frac{y}{x} \right),\ $ although I'm not sure this fact is relevant.

- The quadratic coefficient, i.e. the coefficient of $\ r^2,\ $ again whilst preserving the order of terms in Newton's formula, is

$$ x^r\left(  \frac{1}{1!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right) - \frac{3}{3!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^2 +\frac{11}{4!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^3 - \frac{50}{6!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^4 + \ldots \right)$$

The coefficients of $\ \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^n\ $ are [Stirling numbers of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Table_of_values) divided by factorials.

Now I'm sure all these series converge, by a little bit of work (which I'm working on...) and then the Alternating Series Test and/or/ Ratio Test, since $\ \left\vert \frac{y}{x} \right\vert < 1.\ $ So each coefficient of $\ r^k\ $ exists.

My main question is: is it true that

$$ (x+y)^r = x^r + x^r\left( \frac{1}{1!}\frac{y}{x} - \frac{1}{2!}\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{3!}\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^3 - \frac{6}{4!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^4 + \ldots \right) r + x^r\left( \frac{1}{1!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right) - \frac{3}{3!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^2 +\frac{11}{4!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^3 - \frac{50}{6!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^4 + \ldots \right) r^2 + \ldots\ ?$$

This can be re-written more nicely as:

$$ \left(1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \right)^r = g(r):= 1 + \left( \frac{1}{1!}\frac{y}{x} - \frac{1}{2!}\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{3!}\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^3 - \frac{6}{4!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^4 + \ldots \right) r + \left(  \frac{1}{1!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right) - \frac{3}{3!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^2 +\frac{11}{4!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^3 - \frac{50}{6!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^4 + \ldots \right) r^2 + \ldots$$

which is clearly a power series in $\ r.$

I'm not even sure if $\ g(r)\ $ exists for all values of $\ r\ $ let alone if it is equal to $\ \left(1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \right)^r.$

I'm not sure if the [Riemann Series Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_series_theorem) has anything to say about this, since this is technically not a simple rearrangement of the terms in Newton's formula: more specifically, we have not permuted the terms...

Comment: On the $r$ where the generalized binomial expression converges absolutely, Riemann's theorem says that you are golden.

Comment: The Riemann series theorem says that real-valued absolutely convergent series are the same as unconditionally convergent series. That is to say, you can rearrange the terms of the sum however you want. Collect the powers of $r$ in the sum, and you're done.

Comment: I think I see what you mean now (especially your first comment). I need to make these things concrete and then I will post my own answer then...

Comment: I still don't understand the second sentence in your second comment because $$ x^r + x^r\left( \frac{1}{1!}\frac{y}{x} - \frac{1}{2!}\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{3!}\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^3 - \frac{6}{4!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^4 + \ldots \right) r + x^r\left(  \frac{1}{1!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right) - \frac{3}{3!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^2 +\frac{11}{4!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^3 - \frac{50}{6!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^4 + \ldots \right) r^2 + \ldots\ $$ is not a re-arrangement of the terms in Newton's Binomial formula.

Comment: I think the above series of series *is* always equal to Newton's formula, but you cannot deduce this from the Riemann Series Theorem: you have to use other methods.

Comment: I think we might need something like Fubini's theorem.

Comment: I am sorry, I seem to be missing something, how can this be viewed as a polynomial in $r$ if $r$ appears in the exponent as well?

Comment: @ManateePink I'm not sure what you mean by that. Please elaborate.

Comment: @AdamRubinson, in my understanding a polynomial in a variable $x$ is a linear combination of powers of $x$ where the coefficients do not depend on $x$. (Formally, it is an eventually zero sequence of elements from some set, usually a field or a ring.) However, your coefficients would depend on $r$, therefore it doesn't fulfill the definition of a polynomial.

Comment: Oh, do you just mean, rearrange the terms around the powers of $r$ as if it were a polynomial, not actually trying to create a polynomial?

Comment: @ManateePink If you are referring to $\ x^r,\ $ then I don't think this is a problem because $\ x^r\ $ can be viewed as a constant. You can even factor out all the $\ x^r$'s from the right-hand side of my initial equation and move it over to the left-hand side to get: 

$$ \left(1+\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) \right)^r = 1 + \left( \frac{1}{1!}\frac{y}{x} - \frac{1}{2!}\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{3!}\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^3 - \frac{6}{4!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^4 + \ldots \right) r + \ldots\ $$

I have updated my answer to include this nice re-writing of the equation.

Comment: @AdamRubinson, I have to disagree, that $x^r$ can be viewed as a constant when $r$ is variable, however, you are right, your $g(r) $ is definitely a polynomial in $r$ (or rather a power series, but I get why one would call those polynomials.)

Comment: @ManateePink Think of $\ x,y,r\ $ as real numbers rather than variables. Then my first equation towards the bottom of my question holds if and only if the the second equation with $\ g(r)\ $ holds because all we have done is divided through by $\ x^r,\ $ which is a constant. And the RHS of my second equation is clearly a power series in $\ r.\ $ Does this make it clearer? You are right that I should be using the term "power series" rather than polynomial.

Comment: The "constant" term should be the $r=0$ value, which  is $(x+y)^0=1$. Have you tried$$(x+y)^r=\exp[r\ln(x+y)]=\sum_{k\ge0}\frac{\ln^k(x+y)}{k!}r^k$$(assuming $x+y>0$)?

Comment: @J.G. The result is is obviously true for $r=0.$ I did not think to try that equality you wrote, but it's not clear to me if and when that series is equal to $\ g(r).$ However, I have found another way to prove the result is affirmative for all $\ r \not\in \mathbb{N}.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ (x+y)^r = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{r}{k} x^{r-k} y^k = x^r + \frac{r}{1!} x^{r-1} y^1 + \frac{r(r-1)}{2!} x^{r-2} y^2 + \frac{r(r-1)(r-2)}{3!} x^{r-3} y^3 + \ldots\ .$$

Dividing through by the constant $\ x^r,\ $ we see that the above series converges if and only if

$$ \left(1+\frac{y}{x}\right)^r = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{r}{k} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^k = \underbrace{1}_{a_0} + \underbrace{\frac{r}{1!}}_{a_1} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^1 + \underbrace{\frac{r(r-1)}{2!} }_{a_2} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2 + \underbrace{\frac{r(r-1)(r-2)}{3!} }_{a_3} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^3 + \ldots $$

converges, and we know that this Newton's Generalised Binomial Expansion converges for **all** real $\ r\in\mathbb{R}.$

However, this does *not* immediately imply the series of expanded brackets terms

$$ \underbrace{1}_{b_0} + \underbrace{\frac{r}{1!}}_{b_1}\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^1 + \underbrace{- \frac{r}{2!} }_{b_2} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2 + \underbrace{\frac{r^2}{2!} }_{b_3} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^2 + \underbrace{\frac{2r}{3!} }_{b_4} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^3 + \underbrace{- \frac{3r^2}{3!} }_{b_5} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^3 + \underbrace{\frac{r^3}{3!} }_{b_6} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^3 + \ldots$$

is equal to $\ \left(\ 1+\frac{y}{x}\right)^r:\ $ we have not yet even established if $\ \displaystyle\sum_k b_k \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^k\ $ converges.

We proceed by showing that $\ \displaystyle\sum_k b_k \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^k\ $ converges absolutely, as follows.

$$ \underbrace{1}_{c_0} + \underbrace{ \frac{ \vert r \vert }{1!} }_{c_1} \left\vert \frac{y}{x}\right\vert^1 + \underbrace{ \frac{ \vert r \vert ( \vert r \vert + 1 ) }{2!} }_{c_2} \left\vert\frac{y}{x}\right\vert^2 + \underbrace{ \frac{ \vert r \vert (  \vert r \vert + 1 )(  \vert r \vert + 2 ) }{3!} }_{c_3} \left\vert\frac{y}{x}\right\vert^3 + \ldots $$

is a series of positive terms; this series converges by the [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test), because

$$ \left \vert \frac{c_{k+1}\left\vert\frac{y}{x}\right\vert^{k+1} }{c_{k} \left\vert\frac{y}{x}\right\vert^k} \right \vert = \left\vert \frac{\left \vert r \right \vert + k}{k+1} \right\vert \left\vert \frac{y}{x} \right\vert \overset{k \to \infty}{\to} \vert 1 \vert \left\vert \frac{y}{x} \right\vert = \left\vert \frac{y}{x} \right\vert < 1.  $$

So, splitting $\ c_k\ $ in the previous series up into individual terms by expanding brackets, we get:

$$ 1 + \frac{ \vert r \vert }{1!} \left\vert \frac{y}{x}\right\vert^1 + \frac{ \vert r \vert }{2!} \left\vert \frac{y}{x}\right\vert^2 + \frac{ \vert r \vert ^2 }{2!} \left\vert \frac{y}{x}\right\vert^2 + \frac{ 2 \vert r \vert }{3!} \left\vert\frac{y}{x}\right\vert^3 + \frac{ 3 \vert r \vert ^2 }{3!} \left\vert\frac{y}{x}\right\vert^3 + \frac{ \vert r \vert ^3 }{3!} \left\vert\frac{y}{x}\right\vert^3 + \ldots,\qquad (1) $$

which is a series of positive terms whose limit of partial sums must be equal to $\ \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\ c_{k} \left\vert\frac{y}{x}\right\vert^k,\ $ by the [Monotone Convergence Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem). We can allow any of the terms in $\ (1)\ $ to be negative and it will still converge. In other words, $\ \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^k\ $ converges absolutely.

The first consequence of this is that $\ \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^k\ = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{r}{k} \left(\frac{y}{x}\right)^k,\ $ for all values of $\ r\in\mathbb{R},\ $ because simply grouping together terms in the series $\ \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^k\ $ without changing the order of terms, doesn't change the fact that it converges, nor the value it converges to.

Secondly, by [Fubini's theorem for infinite series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem) (and **not** Riemann Series Theorem), the fact that $\ \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^k\ $ converges absolutely means that $\ \displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^k\ $ is indeed equal to

$$ g(r):= 1 + \left( \frac{1}{1!}\frac{y}{x} - \frac{1}{2!}\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{3!}\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^3 - \frac{6}{4!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^4 + \ldots \right) r + \left(  \frac{1}{1!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right) - \frac{3}{3!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^2 +\frac{11}{4!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^3 - \frac{50}{6!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^4 + \ldots \right) r^2 + \ldots\ $$

for **all** values of $\ r\in\mathbb{R}.$

Thus we finally have our result:

$$\ (x+y)^r = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \binom{r}{k} x^{r-k} y^k = x^r + \frac{r}{1!} x^{r-1} y^1 + \frac{r(r-1)}{2!} x^{r-2} y^2 + \frac{r(r-1)(r-2)}{3!} x^{r-3} y^3 + \ldots\ = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} b_k \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^k\ = g(r):= 1 + \left( \frac{1}{1!}\frac{y}{x} - \frac{1}{2!}\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^2 + \frac{3}{3!}\left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^3 - \frac{6}{4!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^4 + \ldots \right) r + \left(  \frac{1}{1!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right) - \frac{3}{3!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^2 +\frac{11}{4!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^3 - \frac{50}{6!} \left( \frac{y}{x}\right)^4 + \ldots \right) r^2 + \ldots $$

for **all** values of $\ r\in\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: Seems like this would be simpler if you replaced $\frac{y}{x}$ by z.

Comment: True. Is my answer correct though? And are there better answers to the original question?