# Limit involving Stirling numbers of the first kind

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, stirling-numbers

This question arose whilst working on [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4360296/can-we-re-write-newtons-binomial-formula-as-a-polynomial-in-r-without-any).

Let $\ \left[{n\atop k}\right]\ $ denote the $\ (n,k)-$th [Stirling number of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind#Table_of_values).

Define $$ f(n) = \left[{n\atop 1}\right] r\ +\ \left[{n\atop 2}\right] r^2\ +\ \ldots\ + \left[{n\atop n}\right] r^n\ $$

I would like to find all the values of $\ r>0\ $ such that

$$ n \frac{f(n-1)}{f(n)} \to 1\quad \text{as}\ n\to\infty. $$

This is clearly true for $\ r=1,\ $ because $$ f(n) = \left[{n\atop 1}\right]\ + \left[{n\atop 2}\right]\ +\ \ldots\ +\ \left[{n\atop n}\right]\ = n!. $$

But I don't think I know enough about Stirling numbers of the first kind to figure out what happens when $\ r\neq 1.$

Comment: $f(n)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(k+r)$ for any $r$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, $\ f(n) = \prod_{k=0}^{n-1} (k+r).\ $ Thus,

$$ n \frac{f(n-1)}{f(n)} = \frac{n}{(n-1)+r} \to 1\quad \text{as}\ n\to\infty,  $$

and this is true for any $\ r>0,\ $ or any $\ r<0: r\not\in\mathbb{Z}.$